# Windows 7 not finding any updates after clean install

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I just did a clean install of windows 7 professional 64-bit on my skylake build and I was able to install windows 7 fine, I even installed the usb drivers, chipset drivers and the rest of the drivers needed. I installed it from a dvd (it had service pack 1 on it) and had a brand new product key (never used on another pc), even when I go to system properties it says that "windows is activated," but when I plugged my ethernet in and connected to the internet, windows update isn't finding any updates. I open windows update and it has been searching for updates the last 30 minutes now and found nothing, Does anyone knoe what go be wrong because I know the dvd would not have the most recent updates? Yes, my internet works fine I am able to go on google chrome and surf the web.

Comment: Yes, I restarted twice

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updates for Windows 7 are very slow (since Windows 10 launch, it seems).

Microsoft has updated Windows update to make it quicker. For that, ensure that kb3135445 is installed on your computer.

You can get it from http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/

By the way it should get all updates after a while. I experienced to let a PC up during a whole night searching for updates. In the morning, ~270 updates were being installed.

Comment: I guess I should leave my computer on the "windows is checking for update" overnight and let it get all of the updates